# Simplify boolean equation

Tags: boolean

I have a boolean equation, and want to simplify it. Help with it.

```
bool needLoad = isA || (!isA && !isB);
```

and after it i use

```
if (needLoad){
       if (isA)
           rawData = Configuration.GetData();
       if (!isA && !isB)
           rawData = Configuration.GetOtherData();
}
```

Comment: You could remove the `if (needLoad)` test to start with

Comment: what do you want to be simplified? the first part or the second? Does the second part resembles the first or its another story?

Comment: see answer from H2CO3, that's I've searched for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simplify the equation using De Morgan's identities:

```
  isA || (!isA && !isB)
= isA || !(isA || isB)
= isA || !isB
```

Comment: i think someones spamming the downvote. see other answer also. ill upvote both to correct this.

Comment: @Sharky Yes, that's very well possible.

Comment: sry H2CO3, my browser lagged a little so i missed the arrow^^ 
gave you a vote up now!

Answer (score 2):

Your needLoad variable is senseless there..

The following code would have the exact same effect:

```
if (isA)
{
   rawData = Configuration.GetData();
}
else if(!isB)
{
   rawData = Configuration.GetOtherData();
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to test for `!isA`? If we are in the `else` branch then `!isA` must be `true`